# Android - Add different fragments depending on Activity host orientation

Tags: android

I'm facing this problem from a week without success.
I'm trying to load two different fragments: `PortraitTestFrag.java` and `LandscapeTestFrag.java` depending on `Activity` host orientation.

Theese `Fragments` are loaded inside */layout/activity_main.xml* and */layout-land/activity_main.xml* like this:

```
     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigationContainerFragment"      
    android:name="class name#"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

What I want is when my `Activity` host is portrait, `PortraitTestFrag` is loaded and show. When my `Activity` is landscape then `LandscapeTestFrag` should load and show.

Problem is that `PortraitTestFrag` is visible at the startup but when device is rotating `LandscapeTestFrag` is never show even `Activity` is destroyed and recreated. It seem the first loaded `Fragment` has the priority.

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you post some code of how much have you tried ?

Comment: Hi @Umair, You can see my previous question. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543639/android-manage-layouts-landscape

Comment: you can check the current orientation of device and in that check you can load your fragment .

Comment: Thanks @Umair but unfortunately my boss wants this solution and I want to understand if this can works or not

Comment: It will work but it's not the right approach to the problem. Better is to use one fragment and save it's state on orientation change and after that retrieve it.

Comment: your current requirement is everytime you change your device's orientation you will have to remove one fragment and create another which is not good at all.

Comment: @Umair can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: @Umair fragments in my app are completely different. Landscape has a map that Portrait hasn' t for example. I can' t use only one fragment for both portrait and landscape

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to replace fragment on orientation changes at least because you will loose your data saved to bundle or persisted inside ViewModel/Presenter/etc.
It is probably better to use DI or fabrics to change implementation of orientation-specific logic inside fragment.
If you really want to change whole fragment, you can create a proxy fragment which manages switch logic:

```
abstract class BaseSwitchFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_ORIENTATION = "ORIENTATION"
        private const val CHILD_TAG = "CHILD_TAG"
    }

    private var prevOrientation: Int? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_switch, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        prevOrientation = savedInstanceState?.getInt(BaseSwitchFragment.KEY_ORIENTATION)

        if (prevOrientation != resources.configuration.orientation) {
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, buildFragment(), CHILD_TAG)
                    .commit()
        }

        prevOrientation = resources.configuration.orientation

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_ORIENTATION, resources.configuration.orientation)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    private fun buildFragment(): Fragment {
        if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return buildPortraitFragment()
        } else {
            return buildLandscapeFragment()
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun buildPortraitFragment(): Fragment

    protected abstract fun buildLandscapeFragment(): Fragment

}
```

I have not tested this code, but probably it should work. Also I believe that it is possible to optimize this code to prevent recreation of child fragment if it is going to be removed.